# OLAP - levels have  the same name

Tags: mdx, olap

I have the following Hierarchy:

```
 <Dimension name="Locations">
<Hierarchy hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Locations" primaryKey="loc1Id"  uniqueKeyLevelName="loc1Id">
  <Table name="OLAP_Budget"/>
  <Level name="location1" column="location1" uniqueMembers="true"/>
  <Level name="location2" column="location2" uniqueMembers="true"  hideMemberIf="IfBlankName"/>
  <Level name="location3" column="location3" uniqueMembers="true"  hideMemberIf="IfBlankName"/>
</Hierarchy>
```

The problem:

"location1" is exit through  different fiscal Year and has different children in each fiscal year.
I displayed "fiscalYear" dimension in column but when i choose to display values of a specific fiscalYear it display all children overall the fiscalYears.

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello! Can you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Well, SSAS does not know what the relationship between years and locations is - and it is not supposed to. Typically, you'd have data for some combinations and the only way (other than placing Year and Location in the same dimension and building a user-defined hierarchy, which I would not advise as it sounds wrong), is to write your query with NON EMPTY. In example:

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Some Measure]*
    [Date].[Calendar].[Year].&[2011]

} ON 0,
{
    [Location].[Location 1].Members
} ON 1
FROM [Some Cube]
```

shows all Locations on rows, regardless whether they have data against them or not. However, if you modify it to:

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Some Measure]*
    [Date].[Calendar].[Year].&[2011]

} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {
    [Location].[Location 1].Members
} ON 1
FROM [Some Cube]
```

Then you get locations which have data in 2011. This way you could get the result you want.